# Select option with JQUERY in laravel 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, laravel-9

I'm making a form for setting data. so when I select by department and I select the IT department. the data ends there, but here when I select the IT department, what appears instead selects the option by employee. Which part is wrong?

this is the code for addsetting.blade.php:

1. [and this is how the form Mode Alokasi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlpRz.png)
2. dropdown form for "by departement":
   [display when selected By department](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYvZQ.png)
3. value for departemen name:
   [value for department name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtXeL.png)
4. when one of the department names is clicked, what appears instead is Employee Tags
   [department names is clicked,Employee Tags appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szWDV.png)
5. even though the employee tags dropdown should only be for allocation mode "By Tags karyawan"
   [and this is the dropdown menu for the correct employee tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4b6u.png)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mode_company').prop("hidden", true);
  $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", true);
  $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", true);
  $('#jk_employee').prop("hidden", true);
  $('#sm_employee').prop("hidden", true);

  $('#modealokasi').on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.value == 'By Karyawan') {
      $('#mode_company').prop("hidden", true);
      $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", true);
      $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", false);

      $('#mode_employee').on('change', function(a) {
        if (a.target.value == 'Jenis Kelamin') {
          $('#jk_employee').prop("hidden", false);
          $('#sm_employee').prop("hidden", true);
        } else {
          $('#jk_employee').prop("hidden", true);
          $('#sm_employee').prop("hidden", false);
        };
      });
    } else if (e.target.value == 'By Company') {
      $('#mode_company').prop("hidden", false);
      $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", true);
      $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", true);
    } else {
      $('#mode_company').prop("hidden", true);
      $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", false);
      $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="modealokasi">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group col-sm" id="modealokasi">
      <label for="mode" class="col-form-label">Mode Alokasi</label>
      <select name="mode" id="mode" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- Pilih Mode Alokasi --</option>
        <option value="By Company">By Company</option>
        <option value="By Departemen">By Departemen</option>
        <option value="By Karyawan">By Tags Karyawan</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="mode_company">
    <label for="company" class="col-form-label">Company</label>
    <select name="company" id="company" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Company --</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="mode_departemen">
    <label for="id_departemen" class="col-form-label">Departemen</label>
    <select name="id_departemen" id="id_departemen" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Departemen --</option>
      <option value="KONVENSIONAL">KONVENSIONAL</option>
      <option value="IT DEPARTEMEN">IT DEPARTEMEN</option>
      <option value="KEUANGAN">KEUANGAN</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="mode_employee">
    <label for="tags" class="col-form-label">Tags Karyawan</label>
    <select name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Tags --</option>
      <option value="Jenis Kelamin">Jenis Kelamin</option>
      <option value="Status">Status</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="jk_employee">
    <label for="tags" class="col-form-label">Jenis Kelamin</label>
    <select name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Jenis Kelamin --</option>
      <option value="Laki-laki">Laki-laki</option>
      <option value="Perempuan">Perempuan</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="sm_employee">
    <label for="tags" class="col-form-label">Stat. Menikah</label>
    <select name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Status Menikah --</option>
      <option value="Sudah">Sudah</option>
      <option value="Belum">Belum</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never nest your event handlers - instead inquire the other select in the change event

Comment: Something like `$('#mode_employee').on('change', function(a) {
    if ($('#modealokasi').val() === "By Karyawan") {`

Comment: then what is the solution sir?, because the dropdown menu with the id "jk_employee" and "sm_employee" only appears when the user selects "BY TAGS EMPLOYEE" and in "BY TAGS EMPLOYEE" they choose based on "Gender/Status". if they select a gender then a "gender" dropdown will appear sir. this is the first time i make a dropdown like this sir. please help sir

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete because I do not speak your language

But it shows you how to do this

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mode_company').prop("hidden", true);
  $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", true);
  $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", true);
  $('#jk_employee').prop("hidden", true);
  $('#sm_employee').prop("hidden", true);

  $('#mode').on('change', function(e) {
    const val = this.value;
    $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", val !== 'By Karyawan');
    $('#mode_company').prop("hidden", val !== 'By Company');
    $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", val !== 'By Departemen');
  });
  $('#mode_employee').on('change', function(a) {
    const val = this.value
    $('#jk_employee').prop("hidden", val !== 'Jenis Kelamin');
    $('#sm_employee').prop("hidden", val !== 'Status');
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="modealokasi">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group col-sm">
      <label for="mode" class="col-form-label">Mode Alokasi</label>
      <select name="mode" id="mode" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- Pilih Mode Alokasi --</option>
        <option value="By Company">By Company</option>
        <option value="By Departemen">By Departemen</option>
        <option value="By Karyawan">By Tags Karyawan</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="mode_company">
    <label for="company" class="col-form-label">Company</label>
    <select name="company" id="company" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Company --</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="mode_departemen">
    <label for="id_departemen" class="col-form-label">Departemen</label>
    <select name="id_departemen" id="id_departemen" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Departemen --</option>
      <option value="KONVENSIONAL">KONVENSIONAL</option>
      <option value="IT DEPARTEMEN">IT DEPARTEMEN</option>
      <option value="KEUANGAN">KEUANGAN</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="mode_employee">
    <label for="tags" class="col-form-label">Tags Karyawan</label>
    <select name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Tags --</option>
      <option value="Jenis Kelamin">Jenis Kelamin</option>
      <option value="Status">Status</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="jk_employee">
    <label for="tags" class="col-form-label">Jenis Kelamin</label>
    <select name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Jenis Kelamin --</option>
      <option value="Laki-laki">Laki-laki</option>
      <option value="Perempuan">Perempuan</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm" id="sm_employee">
    <label for="tags" class="col-form-label">Stat. Menikah</label>
    <select name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Pilih Status Menikah --</option>
      <option value="Sudah">Sudah</option>
      <option value="Belum">Belum</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```